# Why pointers are shown instead of string in my inorder traversal of BST?

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

Here is the code for printing the inorder traversal of the binary search tree:
    public class BSTPrint {

```
public void printInorder(BSTNode root){
    if (root!=null){
        printInorder(root.getLeftNode());
        System.out.println(root.getNodeValue());
        printInorder(root.getRightNode());
    }

}

public static void main(String[] argc){
    BSTPrint bstPrint = new BSTPrint();
    BSTNode<String> root=new BSTNode<String>();
    root.setNodeValue("5");
    BSTNode<String> rootLeft= new BSTNode<String>();
    rootLeft.setNodeValue("3");
    root.setLeftNode(rootLeft);
    BSTNode<String> rootRight= new BSTNode<String>();
    rootRight.setNodeValue("8");
    root.setRightNode(rootRight);
    bstPrint.printInorder(root);
}
}
```

Here's the BSTNode class:

```
public class BSTNode<E> {
    private E value;
    private BSTNode<E> leftNode=null;
    private BSTNode<E> rightNode=null;

    public BSTNode getLeftNode(){
        return this.leftNode;
    }
    public void setLeftNode(BSTNode rootLeft){
        BSTNode newLeftNode=new BSTNode();
        newLeftNode.leftNode=null;
        this.leftNode=newLeftNode;
        newLeftNode.value=rootLeft;
    }
    public BSTNode getRightNode(){
        return this.rightNode;
    }
    public void setRightNode(BSTNode rootRight){
        BSTNode newRightNode=new BSTNode();
        newRightNode.rightNode=null;
        this.rightNode=newRightNode;
        newRightNode.value=rootRight;
    }

    public E getNodeValue(){
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setNodeValue(E value){
        this.value=value;
    }

}
```

Why am I seeing my result like the following?

```
BSTNode@246f9f88
5
BSTNode@1c52ac68
```

instead of

```
3
5
8
```

Comment: Your generics is all messed up.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but this is how your code should look with proper generics. http://ix.io/l9P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setleft/right are actually wrong:

they should be:

```
public void setRightNode(BSTNode rootRight){
    this.rightNode=rootRight;
}
public void setLeftNode(BSTNode rootLeft){
    this.leftNode=rootLeft;
}
```

You already have a node - so you just need to set it. there is no need to create an extra node object.

Hint: if you look at the java warnings in your ide you will find that it complains that you should parameterize some of your values (always use BSTNode in all parts of BSTNode). Once you add it, it will tell you that it cannot conver BSTNode to E in you set*Node functions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. It makes perfect sense to me now :)

Answer (score 4):

`printInOrder` is working just fine. The left node's value isn't 3; the left node's value is another node, because `setLeftNode`:

```
public void setLeftNode(BSTNode rootLeft){
    BSTNode newLeftNode=new BSTNode();
    newLeftNode.leftNode=null;
    this.leftNode=newLeftNode;
    newLeftNode.value=rootLeft;
}
```

isn't hooking the provided `rootLeft` node into `this.leftNode`. It's creating another node to be the `leftNode` and setting that node's *value* to `rootLeft`. The same problem appears in `setRightNode`.

You need to fix `setLeftNode` and `setRightNode`. Also, if you're using an IDE (such as Eclipse), you know all those places your IDE is showing yellow warning indicators? The ones where if you mouse over them, it says you're not using generics properly? If you had included the `<E>`s when the IDE was warning you about that, the compiler would have caught the bugs in `setLeftNode` and `setRightNode` for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not fresh on my Java, but I think you want to define `BSTNode` left and right node members like so:

```
public class BSTNode<E> {
   private E value;
   private BSTNode<E> leftNode=null;
   private BSTNode<E> rightNode=null;
}
```

Comment: You're using `BSTNode` quite a few times instead of `BSTNode<E>` inside of your `BSTNode<E>` class. I suspect it has to do with that. The logic for printing in order seem fine to me.